# height and bryophytes

Tags: botany, homework

> Why does being taller provide advantages for Bryophyta but being
>   shorter is better for Marchantiophyta? What disadvantages could being
>   taller have?

I think that by being taller, you have better spore dispersal. However, the problem with being tall is that the temperature flucuates more. Am I correct? Is this the right answer? Am I on the right track?

Comment: The root of the question is going to be in the differences between Bryophyta and Marchantiophyta. What are some of those differences? Do they affect spore dispersal? Water use? Temperature?

Comment: @Resonating Bryophyta have a cuticle, stomata, and conductive tissue. But the question is guess is why does it need it? I can only think of water use.  Being tall provides advantages for spor diesperal as well.

Comment: So taller is better. Why isn't Marchantiophyta taller? Can they even *be* any taller than they are?